# Suppress result from insert trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, nocount

A MS SQL insert trigger causes some grief as it returns a result. Is there a way to disable any result from being sent? I've used 'set nocount on', but that doesn't seem to do much...

```
create trigger tr_insert_raw_data
on raw_data
instead of insert
as
begin
 set nocount on

 declare @query varchar(max);
 declare @rev int;
 declare @id int;
 declare @oldrev int;
 declare @contextinfo VARBINARY(128)  

 select @contextinfo = context_info()
 if @contextinfo = 0x00001
 begin
  insert into raw_data select * from inserted
  return
 end

 select * into #query from inserted
 set @id = (select count(distinct id) from raw_data);
 set @id += 1;
 insert into revisions (username, hostname, ts) values (SYSTEM_USER, HOST_NAME(), GETDATE())
 set @rev = (select max(id) from revisions);

 select @oldrev = revision_id from inserted;
 if @oldrev is null set @oldrev=@rev-1;

 select * into #inserted from inserted
 update #inserted set revision_id = @rev, id = @id
 select * from #inserted
 insert into raw_data select * from #inserted
 insert into edges (a, b) values (@oldrev, @rev)
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what kind of a result are you getting? 
After a quick review of your query my first thought is that you're getting results due to the

```
select * from #inserted
```

line you have (third line from bottom). This line tells me that you are requesting results which is probably why you're getting some?

If you do need values selected from a table to modify or custom select out of, perhaps CTE's will help you out?  ([Common Table Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx))

Comment: Oh yes, of course. I had this line in for debugging and forgot to remove it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad I could help. Please indicate the question as answered by selecting my post as the correct answer.
Thanks and Njoy!